# Resolving a second degree inequation using its factored form

Tags: inequality, polynomials

I'm trying to solve an exercise and I'm having troubles to get it right.

We have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ defined as follow :

- $f(x) = 2x-3$
- $g(x) = -x²+x-3$

**Question** : We have to demonstrate that solving $f(x) > g(x)$ is equivalent to solve $x(-x-1)>0$. It is not allowed here to use the polynomial form to solve the inequalities.

**My researches** : I first draw the representative curves of the functions and observed that :

- On $]-\infty;-1]$ we have $f(x) > g(x)$
- On $]-1 ; 0]$ we have $f(x) < g(x)$
- On $]0 ; +\infty[$ we have $f(x) > g(x)$

Then, I tried to develop the inequality $f(x) > g(x)$ as follow:

 $f(x) > g(x)$

 $2x-3 > -x²+x-3$

 $2x-3+x²-x+3 > 0$

 $x² + x >0$

 $x(x+1) > 0$

The two roots here are obviously $x=0$ and $x=-1$ and  for the inequality to be true we must have either $x>0$ or $x<-1$.

However for $x(-x-1) > 0$ to be true we must have $-1<x<0$.

Therefore solving $f(x) > g(x)$ is **NOT** equivalent to solve $x(-x-1)>0$.

**Am I getting something wrong here ? Or is there a mistake in the exercise ?**

Thank you very much for reading this post (that may sound quite silly...).

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Your  reasoning is correct.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is $$x<-1$$ or $$x>0$$